# Why am I getting a null error when mapping over this array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, mapping

I'm trying to map over my API to get the nodes.

Here is the format my API is in:

```
[
    {
        "agent": "....",
        "managementDomain": "...",
        "node": "..."
    },
    {
        "agent": "....",
        "managementDomain": "...",
        "node": "..."
    },
...
]
```

The format I need to get it into for react-select:

```
const colourOptions = [
    { value: 'orange', label: 'Orange' },
    { value: 'yellow', label: 'Yellow' },
    { value: 'green', label: 'Green' },
    ];
```

How I am mapping over it (using Redux for state management):

```
const alarms = this.props.dataReducer.alarmDetails

const {test} = alarms.map(alarm => ({value:alarm.node, label: alarm.node}))
```

The error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of null
```

console.log(this.props.dataReducer.alarmDetails)

```
(288) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, null, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, null, {…}, {…}, null, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, null, null, null, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, null, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]

[0 … 99]
0:
agent: "..."
managementDomain: null
node: "..."
```

What's the best way to map over the API to get the node from each object within the array?

Comment: Not able to understand the code. Please check that have you miss any code snippet?

Comment: I've added the missing code.

Comment: What is the usage of colourOptions ?

Comment: it's the options for react-select drop down.

Comment: Would you please attach the result of "" alarms "" ?

Comment: Yep, just updated the code.

Comment: tbh, I can't see how `colourOptions` is related to the 1st sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is actually self explanatory. Your map code is alright. Problem seem to exist that some of the objects in array is null or empty, so when javascript is trying to find node property on that object, its hitting the rock.

Actually `this.props.dataReducer.alarmDetails` this data contains null value, something like..

```
[
    {
        "agent": "....",
        "managementDomain": "...",
        "node": "..."
    },
    {
        "agent": "....",
        "managementDomain": "...",
        "node": "..."
    },
null
...
]
```

So, maybe you can filter the null values:

```
this.props.dataReducer.alarmDetails.filter(data=>data)
```

and put map code here

```
this.props.dataReducer.alarmDetails.filter(data=>data).map(d => ({value:d.node, label: d.node}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

import "./styles.css";

const alarms = [
  { agent: 1, managementDomain: null, node: "node1" },
  { agent: 2, managementDomain: null, node: "node2" }
];

let teamsFromApi = alarms.map(team => { return {value: team.agent, label: team.node} });

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select options={teamsFromApi} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Note: Replace node data.

You can check the example [Codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-hypatia-6g70r)